# Value of string was rewritten after read a file which the name is the value of the string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, iostream, getline

There are 5 txt files, one ("table_of_content.txt") includes the name of other four txt files, in each four successive lines. And in the other four files, each contain one line of sentence.

There is not problem to read the table txt and use array to restore the string(the names of other files).

But after I try to use getline.() to restore the sentences in the other four files, filenames[number], the string which should restore the name of the four files are rewritten, it become the same as words[number], which restore the sentences.

I am really confused, which part is wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main (){
    ifstream content;
    content.open("table_of_content.txt");
    if (content.fail()){
        cout<< "fails";
        return 0;
    }
    int number = 0, i = 0;
    string filenames[number], words[i];
    while (content >> filenames[number]){
        number++;
    }
    content.close();
    cout << number << " students' files are read" << endl;
    // read table_of_content.txt  
    ifstream input;
    while (i < number){
        input.open(filenames[i].c_str());
        getline(input, words[i]);
        // after this getline, filenames become words
        input.close();
        i++;
    }
    cout << filenames[2] << endl << words[3] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: you don't need the `.c_str()` in `input.open`, it has a `std::string` overload

Answer (score 2):

The definition

```
string filenames[number]
```

is invalid for two reasons:

1. C++ doens't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). The solution is to use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).
2. At the time of the definition, the value of `number` is ***zero***. So you attempt to create an array of zero elements, which is not allowed. The solution to this is to do the definition *after* you get the final value of `number`.

You have the same problem with `words`.

---

Reading the code a little closer, *one* simple solution for `filenames` is to read into a temporary string and then [push the string into the vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back). There are more compact and "C++'ish" solutions, but pushing in a loop is a good start.

That is, you first loop could be something like

```
std::vector<std::string> filenames;
std::string filename;
while (content >> filename){
    filenames.push_back(filename)
}
```

Note that `number` is no longer needed, since the number of elements can be gotten by `filenames.size()`.

You should do something similar with `words`.

Comment: Thank you for you help, but we didn't learn vector yet, and we are asked to store both filenames and words in array, is there any way to use array to do it?

Comment: @FernM Then you have to set a fixed size beforehand, and hope it's big enough (but not to big and waste unused space).